# How To Create New Line In txt File

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

in my web page i am using two textboxes to add record in a text file.
but the problem is that every time when i insert new record,previous record in the text file automatically delete,and the text file contains only the current record.
kindly help me fix this issue.
Thanks.

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="save" OnClick="btn_Click" />
```

and my code behind is like this

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("date.txt"));
        tw.WriteLine(txt1.Text + txt2.Text + System.DateTime.Now);
        tw.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why you are not using StreamWriter for everything (= why relying on TextWriter at all?). Also note that you are not disposing the variable what might provoke errors. Relying on the Using statement is always recommendable when dealing with StreamWriter. Other than that, Shai is right: you are not appending the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have also done like this and it is also working well

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = txt1.Text + "" + txt2.Text+""+System.DateTime.Now;
        string path=Server.MapPath("date.txt");            
        File.AppendAllText(path, text + "\n");            
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Update your TextWriter to enable appending, like this:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("date.txt"), true);
```

Comment: But note that the file has to exist in order to allow appending to not trigger an error.

Comment: but now i am getting an alert that this file has been modified outside the source editor.Do you want to reload it?   How can i resolve it?

Comment: This alert it perfectly ok. You can choose "Yes" to reload the file in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use other overloaded method of StreamWriter which has last parameter as 'Append' and that has to be set to 'true'.

`TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("date.txt"),true);`